# Ruby on Rails VPS RAM amount

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, vps, ram

Currently I have a simpliest VPS: 1 core, 256 MB of RAM, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. My application seems to be running fine enough (I'm using unicorn and nginx) but when I run my `rake jobs:work` command for my `delayed_jobs`, unicorn process is getting killed.

I was wondering if it is related to the RAM amount ?

When the unicorn process is up and running, `free -m` command shows me that around 230 MB of RAM are occupied.
I was wondering, how much RAM would I need in overall ? 512 ? 1024 ? 
Which one should I go with ?

Would be very glad to receive any answers!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DJ worker would run another instance of your Rails application, so you need to make sure that you have at least enough RAM for that other instance plus allowance for other processes you are running.

- Check `ps aux` for the memory usage of your Rails app.
- Run `top` and see how much physical memory is free (while your Rails app is running).

My guess is you'll have to bump up your RAM to 512 MB. You of course don't want your memory use to spill over to swap.

Of course, besides that, you also need to make sure that your application and database are optimized enough that there are no incredible spikes in memory usage.

Comment: I'm pretty happy with my VPS provider. And the next package they offer is 1 GB of RAM. Would that be enough for application itself + DJ ?

Thank you very much for your answer.

I've also wanted to know how much RAM is being allocated to each visitor to the site ? How to estimate it ?

Comment: RAM usage is usually estimated by the number of application instances that you have running. If you have one Rails instance running to handle your web requests, you can serve one web request at a time. If you want to process more than one web request simultaneously, increase your number of instances. Run `ps aux` and see how much memory your Rails app is using. Then multiply this by (your number of web instances + 1 for delayed_job). But check `top` because some of your memory also goes to your OS and the other services that you have running, and see how much more you actually need.

Comment: Ok, that is a bit too complex :) I think, I'll go with 1 Gig or RAM, which should be enough for my site. 

I was curious, it there would be too many visitors at one time - would it kill my HTTP-server (unicorn) process ? Or any other processes, like mysql-server ?

Comment: 1GB might be safe if you have the budget for it. :-) Unicorn will be okay as it will just reject web requests straightaway if the maximum number of backlog requests (unprocessed by your Rails web instances) has been reached. The load for your MySQL server is dependent on the number of web instances you have too.

Comment: Well, I clearly have no other option here :) 256mb or 1 gb (considering, that I wouldn't want to change my provider).

Thank you very much for your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can start with

```
ulimit -S -a
```

to find out the limits of your environment

Comment: core file size (blocks, -c) unlimited,
data seg size (kbytes, -d) unlimited,
scheduling priority (-e) 0,
file size (blocks, -f) unlimited,
pending signals (-i) 772251,
max locked memory (kbytes, -l) 64,
max memory size(kbytes, -m) unlimited,
open files (-n) 1024,
pipe size (512 bytes, -p) 8,
POSIX message queues (bytes, -q) 819200,
real-time priority (-r) 0,
stack size (kbytes, -s) 10240,
cpu time (seconds, -t) unlimited,
max user processes (-u) 772251,
virtual memory (kbytes, -v) unlimited,
file locks (-x) unlimited
That is what I have received! Don't know how to analyze it properly